# Apache Commons CLI - option type and default value

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

How can I give a CLI Option a type - such as `int` or `Integer`? (Later, how can I get the parsed value with a single function call?)

How can I give a CLI Option a default value? Such that `CommandLine.getOptionValue()` or the function call mentioned above return that value unless one is specified on the command line?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**EDIT: Default values are now supported. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14309108/1082541 below.**

As Brent Worden already mentioned, default values are not supported.

I had issues with using `Option.setType` too. I always got a null pointer exception when calling `getParsedOptionValue` on an option with type `Integer.class`. Because the documentation was not really helpful I looked into the source code.

Looking at the [TypeHandler](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/cli/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/cli/TypeHandler.java?view=markup) class and the [PatternOptionBuilder](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/cli/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/cli/PatternOptionBuilder.java?view=markup) class you can see that `Number.class` must be used for `int` or `Integer`.

And here is a simple example:

```java
CommandLineParser cmdLineParser = new PosixParser();

Options options = new Options();
options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withLongOpt("integer-option")
                      .withDescription("description")
                      .withType(Number.class)
                      .hasArg()
                      .withArgName("argname")
                      .create());

try {
    CommandLine cmdLine = cmdLineParser.parse(options, args);

    int value = 0; // initialize to some meaningful default value
    if (cmdLine.hasOption("integer-option")) {
        value = ((Number)cmdLine.getParsedOptionValue("integer-option")).intValue();
    }

    System.out.println(value);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Keep in mind that `value` can overflow if a number is provided which does not fit into an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the example, this is what I needed. However, I have decided against CLI: it's too much work. Maybe it's just me, but I find it self-defeating when you have to handle common cases like that. With enough setup code, I should be able to just say `int foo = getOption("foo")` and have it default to 42 if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I also think the library should handle this stuff. Which option parsing library can you recommend instead??

Comment: I'm new to the Java world. This was the first one I tried, and I know of no others. Perhaps you should post this as a question?

Comment: Thx for pointing out the `Number.class` thing. I naively expected  `Integer.class` to work...!

Answer (score 31):

I do not know if not working or if added recently but [getOptionValue()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.html#getOptionValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) ***has*** an overloaded version that accepts a default (String) value

Comment: This is precisely what I needed 2 years ago :)

Comment: @aib : Glad it helped - did it exist back then ?

Comment: I guess not, else I'd have seen it. (Or someone else here, at least.)

Answer (score 2):

The OptionBuilder is deprecated in version 1.3 & 1.4 and `Option.Builder` doesn't seem to have a direct function to set the type. There is a function for the `Option` class called `setType`. You can a retrieve a converted value with the function `CommandLine.getParsedOptionValue`.
Not sure why it's not part of the builder anymore. It requires some code like this now:

```
    options = new Options();

    Option minOpt = Option.builder("min").hasArg().build();
    minOpt.setType(Number.class);
    options.addOption(minOpt);
```

and reading it:

```
    String testInput = "-min 14";
    String[] splitInput = testInput.split("\\s+");

    CommandLine cmd =  CLparser.parse(options, splitInput);
    System.out.println(cmd.getParsedOptionValue("min"));
```

which would give a variable of type `Long`

Answer (score 1):

CLI does not support default values.  Any unset option results in `getOptionValue` returning `null`.

You can specify option types using the [Option.setType](http://commons.apache.org/cli/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/cli/Option.html#setType%28java.lang.Object%29) method and extract the parsed option value as that type using [CommandLine.getParsedOptionValue](http://commons.apache.org/cli/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.html#getParsedOptionValue%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I'm aware of the existence of setType() and getParsedOptionValue(), but have no idea how to use them. Could you give me a small example?

Answer (score 0):

One can use other definition of

```
getOptionValue:
public String getOptionValue(String opt, String defaultValue)
```

and wrap your default value to string.

Example:

```
String checkbox = line.getOptionValue("cb", String.valueOf(false));
```

output: false

it worked for me